# Can i recover my private key with the keystore file?

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, keystore

I have a wallet on myetherwallet.com.
I lost my private key. I am still able to open my wallet using the keystore JSON file.

Can i have my private key back? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On https://www.myetherwallet.com, click "View Wallet Info" and then select your keystore JSON file. Once you enter your password to decrypt it, you'll see your private key.